# How to handle Custom listview item clicks?

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with custom listview item click.

In my activity I have a button and a custom ListView such that on clicking the button, checkboxes appear to left of each item, and again on clicking the button, checkboxes disappear.By default on clicking the item, it should display Toast1, and on clicking the button(when checkboxes enabled), it should display Toast2.So the button acts like a toggle button.

So I have written `ListView.onitemclickListener` in Activity to display Toast1 and `convertView.setOnClickListener` in getView to display Toast2.

In getView(), I have written :

```
if(myFlag)
{
  convertView.setOnClickListener ... 
  {
      display Toast2
  }
}
```

here myFlag will be set true/false based on the toggle button.

But when after clicking toggle button and clicking on listview item, sometimes its displays Toast1 and sometimes Toast2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solved this myself. 
Just set the setclickable() of convertView to true/false in getView() method. If set to true Toast2 will displayed() and if set to False Toast1 will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding different OnClickListeners at runtime can cause some Problems, especially if you tie it to the getView() Method.

If you use a single onClickListener and check for your flag there, it should be working the way you want to.

Pseudocode:

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener ... 
  {
       if(myFlag){
       hide checkbox;
       display Toast2;
       myFlag =false;
     }
      else {
       show checkbox;
       display Toast 1;
       myFlag =true;
     }

}
```

Comment: Actually instead of Toast1 I should play a song. Hence it should be written in Activity in my project.

Comment: What exactly is the Problem with starting the song inside the clicklistner? You can acess your activity from inside the listener with view.getContext()

Comment: I have a lot of complex code inside the listview.itemclick - variables,broadcasts etc. I just want to know how can I handle the clicks in both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I use setTag()/getTag() methods for getting the position of the item. In the getView() method of the list adapter set position of the item as the tag of the row items(in your case button) using **setTag("position")** method.
When the button in any row is clicked the onClick() method will be called for that button and in the onClick() method you can use **getTag()** method to get the position. Use same method as the onClick routine for all the rows button.

sample code: List item could be something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grad"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

getView() method could be something like this:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    ...
    button.setTag(position);
    ...
}
```

onClick routine could be something like this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    if(tag != null) {
         int position = Integer.parseInt(tag);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually my question is slightly different from your answer.I dont have button in each row and nothing to do with position here. BTW i can get the position directly on listview.itemclick. Anyway i learnt a new topic setTag and getTag. Thanks for this

Comment: are both the list view item click and view click are working simultaneously for you???

Comment: yes, they are working. if setclickable() of convertview is set to false - listview item click is working. and if it is set to true - view click in getView() is working.

Comment: I asked simultaneously....both of them cannot work simultaneously (untill and unless you pass the click of one to the other). One of them has to be disabled as you are doing with setClickable() of convertview...

Comment: I got your point now. Anyway i want only one to work at a time.

Comment: then you can use any one of the approach either setClickable() on the convertView or setTag()/getTag() pair.